# Rapidjson parse another json if first one has errors

Tags: c++, rapidjson

Say I have a JSON string and it has an error and thus can not be parsed. Then I want to parse another JSON string, which will replace the original one. I want to do that using the same `rapidjson::Document` as eventually I need to have parsed the valid JSON in that document.

So:

```
rapidjson::Document document;
if (document.Parse<0>("{ \"hello\" : \"wor........ ").HasParseError())
{
    // How to parse the correct json "{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }" here
    // using the same `Document` ?
}
```

Should I just write

```
if (document.Parse<0>("{ \"hello\" : \"wor........ ").HasParseError())
{
   document.Parse<0>("{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }"); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if first parsing hes error then parsing another JSON by using the same `document` is OK, as far as it clears that data and parses newly.